# Interpretation of t-tests

Tags: t-test

I have a really *simple question which bothers me periodically when I think about it*. This question is about an elementary notion in statistics: t-tests.

### Intro

Assume that I got $\hat{\beta}$ from a regression and that I want to test the significance of the difference there is between it and any other value, say, $\widetilde{\beta}$.

Let first do a **unilateral test** (which, I think, does not really bother me, the bilateral case does and follows thereafter), and let us test how likely it is for the real (non-observed) $\beta$ to be $\widetilde{\beta}$, given the $\hat{\beta}$ one estimated. Put differently:

$H_0$ : $ \hat{\beta} = \widetilde{\beta}$

$H_1$ : $ \hat{\beta} < \widetilde{\beta}$

To test this, what one does is calculating the distance, denoted by $d$, in terms of (estimated) standard errors, denoted by $\widehat{se}$, between $\hat{\beta}$ and $\widetilde{\beta}$, as follows:

$d = \frac{\hat{\beta} - \widetilde{\beta}}{\widehat{se}}$

and one then checks, using a t-distribution or a standard normal distribution, denoted by $\Phi$, how likely is $d$:

$p = \Phi(d)$

where $p$ is the probability value (p-value) of the event stated in $H_1$.

---

### Question

Let then do a **bilateral test**.

$H_0$ : $ \hat{\beta} = \widetilde{\beta}$

$H_1$ : $ \hat{\beta} \neq \widetilde{\beta} \iff \hat{\beta} - \widetilde{\beta} \neq 0$

$d$ is computed as before, and $p=2\Phi(d)$.

$H_1$ could be rephrased as

$H_1$ : $(d  < 0$ 
***OR*** 
$d> 0) \iff d \neq 0$

whence the (distribution symmetry based) pvalue of $2\Phi(d)$. Recalling that $d\times \widehat{se}$ is the (alternatively hypothesized) distance from $\hat{\beta}$, be it on the left ($d<0$) or on the right ($d>0$).

Using the relation there is between t-tests and confidence intervals, $H_1$ can be rephrased in term of the true $\beta$, as

$H_1$ : $\beta \leq \hat{\beta}-|d|\times \widehat{se}$
***or***
$\beta \geq \hat{\beta}+|d|\times \widehat{se}$

while only one of the these two threshold values was at first of interest (either $\hat{\beta}-|d|\times \widehat{se}$ or $\hat{\beta}+|d|\times \widehat{se}$). It follows that $H_0$ could also be rephrased in term of the true $\beta$ as

$H_0$ : $\hat{\beta} - |d| \times \widehat{se} < \beta < \hat{\beta} + |d| \times \widehat{se}$

***What bothers me is that*** the alternative hypothesis actually involves two critical thresholds, with one which was not of interest at first. For example, in the case of a significance test, i.e. $\widetilde{\beta}=0$, one would thus define the following hypothesis framework

$H_0$ : $0 < \beta < 2\hat{\beta}$

$H_1$ : $\beta \leq 0$
***or***
$\beta \geq 2\hat{\beta}$

In this case, ***do you agree that*** one does not mind about $\beta \geq 2\hat{\beta}$, right ? So why would one do a bilateral test in this case?

---

[Discussed in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62636/discussion-between-user43849-and-kanak) but I am still waiting for someone who tells me, e.g. *no, you are definitely wrong because ...*. A two-lines answer may be sufficient.

---

I am curious of this -1. I would be glad to know why.

---

***Update/correction*** following Whuber's comments. ***Be critical, I may not have caught everything said ! Did I ?***

I actually *went off the rails at*

> [...] , $H_1$ can be rephrased in term of the true $\beta$, as [...]

First let redenote objects that were previously involved

$d_0 = \frac{\beta-\beta_0}{se} \sim \Phi $

where $\beta_0$ is ***any*** tested value (previously called $\widetilde{\beta}$ and renamed simply for the sake of coherence vis-à-vis of the null-hypothesis name), $\Phi$ is either a [student or standard normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212513/should-we-apply-z-test-or-t-test-for-testing-the-difference-between-two-sample-m), followed by $d_0$.

But, given that the $\beta$ and $se$ are random variables whose expectations are only known [asymptotically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_theory_(statistics)), one uses, in the absence of any more reliable information, the estimates of these expectations, commonly denoted by $\widehat{\beta}$ and $\widehat{se}$ to compute this so-tested $\beta_0$-specific distance, i.e.

$d_0 = \frac{\widehat{\beta}-\beta_0}{\widehat{se}}$

With the parametric/parametrized knowledge of the distribution of $d_0(\beta_0)$ -- distribution whose parameters consist of a [degrees of freedom in the case of the student distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) or of a [0-mean and unit variance in the case of the normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution) (whence the term *standard*) -- one can characterize how likely is $H_0$'s statement. Let recall the two hypotheses:

$H_0$ : $ \widehat{\beta} = \beta_0 \iff d_0 = 0$

$H_1$ : $ \widehat{\beta} = \beta_1 \neq \beta_0 \iff d_0 = d_1 \neq 0$

And one has $\text{Pr}\left(H_0 \ \text{is True}\right) = 1 - 2\Phi\left(d_0\right)$ . Which furthermore means that if one takes for granted that $H_0$ is True, the probability that one actually is wrong is $2\Phi\left(d_0\right)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62636/discussion-between-user43849-and-kanak).

Comment: You went off the rails at "H1 can be rephrased in term of the true β, as ..." because the statement that followed is an assertion about a sampling statistic $\hat \beta$: it's not a hypothesis about a parameter. All subsequent statements about hypotheses appear to be equally erroneous.

Comment: @whuber. Once again thx. Isn't it the same sort of assertion which makes the *link* between t-tests and confidence intervals ?

Comment: The link is provided through the sampling distributions of test statistics.  Those should not be confused with hypotheses.  A hypothesis is a statement about the model for the data.  The null hypothesis is sufficiently specific that the sampling distribution of the test statistic can be deduced from it, but that is all.

Comment: Thank you for continuing to improve your question.  You seem to be confused about what a hypothesis is.  By definition, *it is a statement about the properties of the model*.  Almost always, it makes an assertion about a parameter.  On the contrary, "$\hat d = 0$" can only be understood as a statement *about the data*, not about the model--and it is found to be true or not by computing $\hat d$ and seeing whether it actually is zero.

Comment: The is no "true $d$".  Your $d$ is not a property of the distribution, because it is a function of the data as well as of the distribution.  It is a random variable.

Comment: Please review our posts, or a good textbook, about hypothesis testing.  This occurs in a framework where the data are assumed to be governed by some definite probability law $F$.  A hypothesis makes a definite, quantitative statement about some property of $F$, say $\delta(F)$--which is a *fixed number* (albeit unknown). Putting aside any questions about the validity of the model, this meets all the qualifications of a "true" and "real" property. So far, none of the statements you have advanced as "hypotheses" are of this nature, which is why they are all invalid.

Comment: @Whuber Books, be them good, are unclear, trapped in unnecessary complicated vocabulary, with gaping omission, using incomplete notations, never clearly showing how things are computed, etc... I can give you such a big list of notions exposed like so. When I read statistic codes (Fortran, R, python, matlab, or whatever), I see how things are computed, and I can play with objects easily. All my understanding comes from codes. And when I ask something, I always know how to compute the objects that I involve. So I know exactly when/where spaces, be them sample or probability related, are implied.

Comment: I won't defend all stats books, because many are as you describe.  But there are excellent introductory ones at all levels.  If you don't study one of them to acquire a working knowledge of the foundation of statistical theory and thought, then (as many of us have been) you will be doomed to puzzle over the alien vocabulary, terse explanations, etc. in everything you read.  Some of our "references" threads include recommendations of intro stats books ranging from high school through professional levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer *my* original question. There are no second value of "non-interest" that are tested when performing a bilateral test, since the distance, $d_0(\beta_0)$, ensures that our concerns are $0$-centered on only one (non-)equality.